# Create SqlConnection in a .NET Standard 2.0 project

Tags: sql, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

How can I create a connection to my local database in a .NET Standard project? Because I want to use that in combination with an UWP application (no EF support).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

Comment: @LeeO. That is for SQLITE

Comment: To use EF Core, install the package for the database provider(s) you want to target. This tutorial uses SQLite. For a list of available providers see Database Providers.

Comment: The tutorial is using SQLite but you can use full SqlServer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases

Comment: @LeeO. Yes I saw that, but I wanted to split the SQL stuff up into a .NET Standard project

Comment: https://garywoodfine.com/using-ef-core-in-a-separate-class-library-project/

Comment: the tools is the tough part. Looks like you have to setup migrations in a project that targets a specific platform (core/framework/uwp/etc) but can do the rest in the .net standard project.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't read it fully, but it seems I don't have to set the connectionstring into the UWP project?

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't read it fully, but it seems I don't have to set the connectionstring into the UWP project?

You're right. You could set the connection string to initilize the `SqlConnection` object and then connect to your local database.

You could check the [Northwind Sample – UWP app connecting to SQL Server](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/IgniteDemos/tree/master/NorthwindDemo) to learn how to do it.